# Better way to convert pandas dataframe columns to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a dataframe with some columns containing data of type object because of some funky data entries (aka a . or whatnot).

I have been able to correct this by identifying the object columns and then doing this:

```
obj_cols = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object]
conv_cols = obj_cols.convert_objects(convert_numeric='force')
```

This works fine and allows me to run the regression I need, but generates this error:

```
FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.
```

Is there a better way to do this so as to avoid the error? I also tried constructing a lambda function but that didn't work.

Comment: You can use astype(int) or pd.to_numeric

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Convert_objects is deprecated. Use this instead.
You can add parameter errors='coerce' to convert bad non numeric values to NaN.

```
conv_cols = obj_cols.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')
```

The function will be applied to the whole DataFrame. Columns that can be converted to a numeric type will be converted, while columns that cannot (e.g. they contain non-digit strings or dates) will be left alone.

Comment: This gave me: Value Error: ('Unable to parse string "." at position...)

Comment: I tried that earlier. I get `TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series`

Comment: Because obj_cols is a dataframe

Comment: The answer with apply should work along with the argument errors = 'coerce'

Comment: i believe `errors = 'coerce'` converts all non-digit strings to NaN , so it rather should be `errors='ignore'`

Comment: @Vrun, errors - ignore returns the original data type

Comment: well, worked for me, converting 
`Data columns (total 9 columns):
strategy          1282 non-null object
Actual Weight     1282 non-null object
Current Price     1282 non-null object` to 
`df_final.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1282 entries, 0 to 1281
Data columns (total 9 columns):
strategy          1282 non-null object
Actual Weight     1282 non-null float64
Current Price     1282 non-null float64
Index Member      1282 non-null object
Percent Weight    1282 non-null float64
Crncy_x           1282 non-null object`

Comment: @Vrun, may be read through the docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858746/ignore-errors-in-pandas-astype)?

Comment: @Vaishali,  i see it might be my df does not have any errors so it successfully converts

Answer (score 3):

If you have a sample data frame:

```
sales = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 'f', 'Mar': 140},
     {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 'e', 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},
     {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 'g' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
```

and you want to get rid of the strings in the columns that should be numeric, you can do this with pd.to_numeric

```
cols = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)
```

your new data frame will have NaN in place of the 'wacky' data