# Ignore errors in pandas astype

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

I have a numeric column that could contain another characters different from 0-9. Say:

```py
x = pandas.Series(["1","1.2", "*", "1", "**."])
```

Then I want to **convert** that Series into a numerical column using

```py
x.astype(dtype = float, errors = 'ignore')
```

I can't figure out why Pandas keeps giving me an error despite the fact that I set `errors='ignore'`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think you want to use [pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) instead:

```
In [73]: x = pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')

In [74]: x
Out[74]:
0    1.0
1    1.2
2    NaN
3    1.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

PS actually `x.astype(dtype = float, errors = 'ignore')` - works as expected, it doesn't give an error, it just leaves series as it is as it can't convert some elements:

```
In [77]: x.astype(dtype = float, errors = 'ignore')
Out[77]:
0      1
1    1.2
2      *
3      1
4    **.
dtype: object   # <----- NOTE!!!

In [81]: x.astype(dtype = float, errors = 'ignore').tolist()
Out[81]: ['1', '1.2', '*', '1', '**.']
```

Comment: Thanks for the `.to_numeric` solution. But I don't know if it's due to my pandas version, it keeps printing **ValueError: could not convert string to float: '**.'**

Comment: @Neroksi, I'm using Pandas 0.23.0. What is your Pandas version?

Comment: My Pandas version is : 0.19.2

Comment: thank you! this was not intuitive, pandas.astype probably should have similar option errors='coerce' option as pandas.to_numeric

Answer (score 2):

In general, if there could be invalid input, instead of `astype`, there are dedicated `pd.to_*` functions that coerces errors so that invalid parsings will be set to NaN.

For strings -> numbers conversion, if there could be non-numeric strings, the following does the job (as @MaxU mentioned):

```py
data = pd.to_numeric(data, errors='coerce')
```

For string/numbers -> datetime/timedelta, `to_datetime` / `to_timedelta` could be used:

```py
data = pd.to_datetime(data, errors='coerce')
data = pd.to_timedelta(data, errors='coerce')
```

---

A convenient aspect of `astype` is that it can be called on a dataframe to convert every column into a specific dtype. Since `to_*` functions are top level functions (not DataFrame methods), `apply` could be used to convert every column.

```py
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# only convert columns A and C
df = df.assign(**df[['A', 'C']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'))
```